# Feature request, self-flagging own comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I would like to suggest an extension of the already functionality «flagging comments» to draw the attention of moderators.  At present, it is possible to mark comments *by other authors*.

Based on a current ongoing discussion [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/157387/how-can-i-add-double-bonds-to-triazine-derivatives-for-openbabel-generation-of-p?noredirect=1#comment322013_157387), I would like to have the possibility to flag a comment *I wrote* to draw the attention of the moderators.  I perceive the question relevant to chemistry and the argumentation of the OP professional.  However over the ongoing discussion in the comments (OP has not yet enough reputation to access the chat rooms) I start think that the question would be *more* suitable for mattermodelling.se, than chemistry.se.

While indicated with a putative `@moderators` (perhaps this handle does not exist), I guess chances this entry were recognized quickly by the moderators were higher if I could «self flag» a comment.

Edit:  The answers by two of the moderators are convincing, the request is retracted.

Comment: Some clarification: the `@` handles only work for users who participate in the discussion, editors of the post, and bounty posers. So `@moderators` would only do something if a user with that handle is one of the given.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't really see the necessity for this, to be honest. You can already flag *the post* for moderator attention, which accomplishes the same effect. If you additionally want to make the "flag text" public, then you can leave a comment; even a copy-pasted one is fine. Or you can comment first and then flag the post and ask us to look at the comment.

Comment: Damn ;) seconds ... mere seconds.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to draw the attentions of the moderators, do not flag comments, flag the post and include whatever the comment says there.

There is in principle only one action for flags on comments: delete. And whatever the comment was about, further investigation into what additional steps need to be taken.

With custom flags on posts there can be communicated a lot more and it won't get lost in noise.

In this case another option would have been to cast a custom close vote suggesting migration and custom flag.

I personally reject this proposal.

Comment: Yours and the answer by @orthocresol convince me to retract my feature request.